# Django design patterns with an engine

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I do not have code to discuss this. But more of a conceptual issue.

Say the user would upload some file through a web file page or input some parameters via a page.

Models.py would be storing all the data which I would need to have stored in my database.

My question would be say after the user submits the webpage data via a form. Where should I put my processing logic? In **forms.py**? If it's a complex process what should be a proper design pattern to put this code?

Comment: Good. You can start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Why the reference to Django tutorial? I am somewhat familiar with it. Just checking on whether should I place the processing logic in forms.py or somewhere else?

Comment: if you are familiar with Django, then you already know that forms.py or models.py or anything-else.py is just a module or submodule in the system. models.py is an abstraction to allow identification of all models. Similarly, forms.py for forms. However, if the processing is complex logic, then may be you'd want to put the logic in utils.py and use it during form processing. But all this is is your choice, nobody can guide you on this without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't definitely have to have only **views.py**. You can specify any other place that handles your request. I guess if you have a lot of different request it would be a good practice to separate them by module. So your **view.py** won't have 1000 methods or so.

[image]

- You can handle all requests in **views.py** that would call another module that contains application logic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Django's typical pattern, you'd handle the request in your app's views.py file. It is simply by convention, you are free to place your code anywhere, but if you are learning and following along with tutorials, views.py is normally where this logic would be expected.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/

If your model uses [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.FileField%20FileField), the uploaded files are not stored in the database, rather uploaded files are stored in path specified in your project settings [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) value. The database FileField stores a relative reference to the file path from MEDIA_ROOT.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/